# Custom Start Number for Order Numbers in Magento 1.5

Tags: magento, configuration, e-commerce, magento-1.5

How do I customise the starting number for orders, invoices etc in Magento 1.5?

Comment: There's an easy to use extension for this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-invoice-shipment-numbers.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From magento's forum:

- [by LindyKyaw (Magento Team Member)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10985/#t130471), changing start number (through sql query):

> ```
> There is a table in the database which stored increment id of order.
> It is called “eav_entity_store” table.
> You can check which entity type id belongs to which entity by looking at 
> eav_entity_type table.
> You can run following query to update last increment id for the order.
>
>     update eav_entity_store
>     inner join eav_entity_type on eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
>     set eav_entity_store.increment_last_id=3001 
>     where eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
> ```

- [by FOOMAN (active contributor)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43830/), changing start number (through db management tool) and removing "0"s at the beginning:

> ```
> With a tool like phpmyadmin look at your database. In the table 
> eav_entity_type you will find all entity types listed. The one of interest to 
> change where the order number starts is order sales/order. Remember the 
> entity_type_id (in my install it is 11). To remove the leading zeros 
> (padding) set increment_pad_length to 1.
> ```

Next go to the table eav_entity_store. Look up the entity_type_id. Now you 
can change the value of increment_prefix and increment_last_id. If you wanted to 
have your next orderId to be 15000 set increment_last_id to 14999 and 
increment_prefix to 0.

Additionally you need to make a copy of this file
/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment/Abstract.php
to
/app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment/Abstract.php 
    `public function getPadLength()
    {
        $padLength = $this->getData('pad_length');
        if (empty($padLength)) {
           $padLength = 0;
        }
        return $padLength;
    }
    ...
    public function format($id)
    {
        $result= str_pad((string)$id, $this->getPadLength(), $this->getPadChar(), STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return $result;
    }` Hope That Helps

Answer (score 3):

**Magento Order No**
It's simple....

- go to phpmyadmin
- select your datbase and then select the table "eav_entity_store"
- in this table, change the `increment_last_id` (for example, I have set 3456767 in my table)
- after that I create a new order. Now my orders start from the number 346768

Comment: I tried this and it works well for the order number, but the order id is different.  Example, when I place an order and I click on the order details, the url is: sales/order/view/order_id/7/

Answer (score 3):

Actually with the newer versions (and probably in 1.5 as well), there is an easier way to change it. In PHPMyAdmin, or your mysql client, go to the `eav_entity_type` table. Locate the table in the `entity_type_code` column (probably `order`), and set the `increment_pad_length` to be whatever you would like, as well as the `increment_pad_char`.

Then you don't have to rewrite core code - a win-win.

JMax

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a [good extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-id-8210.html) for accomplish this task.

It allows you to customize the order ID in a lot of different way:
for example you can use a combination of:

1. number like year,month,,day,hr,sec,
2. use a custom counter (you can decide the starting number )
3. a combination of all above methods
4. add some custom string in any position of the order ID

This is the ext. on Magento connect:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-id-8210.html

I personally tried it and it very good ( works fine with all my payment methods and I had no issue at all )