# Change Magento Order ID/Invoice Number in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin

Okay so I am having a hard time figuring this out I need to change the next order number from 100XXX to what ever I want how would I go about doing this?

I am very new to all this so if you could give me detailed instructions it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

To change Order Number

Update `increment_last_id` in `eav_entity_store` table. To find the correct entity_type_id for order do

**Find the entity_type_id for orders**

`SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'order';`

See

- [Changing Magento Order, Invoice and Shipping Number](http://chilipepperdesign.com/2009/07/09/changing-magento-order-invoice-and-shipping-numbers/)
- [How to Change the Order Increment ID and Prefix in Magento](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/)
- [How to Change Order Starting Number in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419592/how-to-change-order-starting-number-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

There's a free extension that will do it for you. `Aschroder_SetStartOrderNumber` Faster to install than for me to find its name and make this answer.